# EF Core 6 generates additional foreign key, even though original is mapped

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two entities with a one-to-many relationship:

```
public class EventEntity : Entity
{
    // ...
    public List<EventCommentEntity> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class EventCommentEntity : Entity
{
    // ...   
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public EventEntity Event { get; set; }
}
```

And configuration for `EventEntity`:

```
public class EventEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<EventEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EventEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasMaxLength(36)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsFixedLength();
            
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        
         //...
        builder.HasMany<EventCommentEntity>()
            .WithOne(x => x.Event)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

When I generate a migration with EF Core 6, it creates two foreign keys:

```
EventId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(36)", fixedLength: true, maxLength: 36, nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
EventEntityId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(36)", nullable: true)
```

Same setup like this working in my other project, I checked every single line but can't get it work, no matter what, it generates both keys. Is there something I miss, or can do to have only one FK?